# Magento 2: How to get value from attribute from store_id 0 (admin/unique)?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-options

I'm trying to get store label for admin (store 0 - zero) but since I have something in "Default Store Label" I'm getting only that value. I need to find the solution to get always only the admin (unique) value. If solution will be like override/plugin for core - that will be applicable too.

Code which I'm using:

```
//($this->attributeOptionManagement = \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface)

$existingOptions = $this->attributeOptionManagement->getItems(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
foreach ($existingOptions as $existingOption) {
    $this->existingOptions[$attributeCode][] = $existingOption->getLabel();
}
```

So if I have this:

[image]

I will have this output based on my code:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  
    [1] => Black
    [2] => Charcoal
    [3] => Cream
    [4] => Gray
    [5] => Green
    [6] => Lightning
    [7] => Natural
    [8] => Olive
)
```

And if I have this:

[image]

The output will be like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  
    [1] => BLACK
    [2] => CHARC
    [3] => CRBBL
    [4] => GR/NA
    [5] => GYCHR
    [6] => LTHTG
    [7] => NATUR
    [8] => OLIVE
)
```

Comment: Where did you add your code?

Comment: I have my custom extension

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: Is it working for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried this code and it works fine for me:

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color')->setStoreId(0);
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($options as $existingOption) {
        echo $existingOption['label'];
    }
?>
```

Can you inject the class **\Magento\Eav\Model\Config** and try this solution.
Above code is tested. Also you can try the below code but its not tested.

```
$existingOptions = $this->attributeOptionManagement->getItems(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode)->setStoreId(0);
```

Comment: The first method works fine! Thank you very much! I will test second and reply. P.S.: For people looking for an answer - don't use ObjectManager directly in your code. It's good for a quick demo but not good for production code.

Comment: Unfortunately second method doesn't work. There are no such method as `setStoreId()`.

Comment: I have used object manager just to guide you how to get admin values but yes its not a good practice. Thanks @Fred. Happy Coding.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, setOptions is not working for me, storing only for Admin view, can you please help on this

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I am getting below error after creating boolean attribute Class Attribute name does not exist, here is my new question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261542/error-after-creating-boolean-attribute-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use below to get default attribute text

```
$_condition = $_product->getAttributeText('condition');
$prod= $_product->setStoreId(0);
$_coditionDefault =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('condition')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the admin value of an attribute :

```
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME');
$adminValue = $attribute
              ->setStoreId(0) // Admin store ID
              ->getSource()->getOptionText($product->getData('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME'));
```