# Error after creating boolean attribute magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, eav-attributes

I have created a boolean attribute using below code.

```
  $setup = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Setup  \ModuleDataSetupInterface');
        $eav_setup_factory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');   
        $setup->startSetup();       
        $eavSetup = $eav_setup_factory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $AttributeCode = "test_attribute";
        $AttributeName = "Test Attribute";
        $type = 'int';
        $input_type = 'boolean';

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                 $AttributeCode,
                 [
                     'type' => $type,
                     'backend' => '',
                     'frontend' => $AttributeName,
                     'label' => $AttributeName,
                     'input' => $input_type,
                     'class' => '',
                     'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                     'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                     'visible' => true,
                     'required' => false,
                     'user_defined' => true,
                     'default' => '0',
                     'searchable' => false,
                     'filterable' => false,
                     'comparable' => false,
                     'visible_on_front' => true,
                     'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                     'unique' => false,
                     'apply_to' => ''
                 ]
            );
```

Attribute created but when try to open I am getting this error.

```
Class "Test Attribute" does not exist.
```

can anyone look into this issue and update me please.

I need to create Yes/No attribute for product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `$AttributeName` is not defined. and you use that variable for `frontend` and `label`.
I assume you changed your code before posting it here and you have somewhere `$AttributeName = 'Attribute label'`.
You need to remove `'frontend' => $AttributeName,`. Maybe replace it with `'frontend' => '',`

Comment: hi @Marius, sorry its my mistake, updated my question

Comment: so my suspicion was right. My answer stands

Comment: no, I forgot to add that variable in question, attribute created successfully, once it is clicked in admin, i am getting that error,

Comment: Read my answer carefully. You need to remove the line `'frontend' => $AttributeName` or replace it with  `'frontend' => ''`. Delete your attribute and recreate it again with my suggestion.

Comment: hi @marius, then how to update the label for attribute if removed frontend?

Comment: frontend does not mean what you thing it means. It is a model (class) that is used for  processing the attribute value before showing it. Just leave it empty.