# Get admin attribute label

Tags: magento2.3, attributes

How can I get the Admin attribute label as shown in the pics?

I can get the frontend store label for each store view in this way:

```
$attribute = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('format');                                
$attr_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
```

but I don't know how I can get the Admin label. Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: you means you get attribute values ??? If Yes, First you write attribute code `$_product->getAttributeText('material');` and get attribute value like `$result = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('material')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`

Comment: Hi, no. I mean the Admin attribute value, not the frontend attribute value (English or Italian in my case).

Comment: Please check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241999/85907

Comment: Thanks but how should I get the admin attribute value from the product ($_item in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```php
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```